# How to set position of create schedule panel with function

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, calendar

I am using Toast UI Calendar for schedule task manager.
My project is Laravel.

If I select left day and center day, it is shown all.
But if I select right-end day, the create panel is cut by screen.
So I want to show it in screen with functions supported in toast ui calendar witout css fixing.

Position of popup panel is set like below code...

```
popup_layer.style.left = e.guide.guideElements[e.guide.startCoord[1]].style.left;
```

These are screenshots:

[image: This is right-end clicking screenshot.]
[image: This is center clicking screenshot. This is good.]

Answer (score 1):

If You click the date, you can get this left value of popup dialog.
And need to get right-end clicking popup left value, then need to set **case statement** or **if statement** with *that value*.

Like ...

```
if(get_valueof_rightend > limit_value)
  popup_layer.style.left = limit_value;
else
  popup_layer.style.left = e.guide.guideElements[e.guide.startCoord[1]].style.left;
```

if left-end clicking popup position is okay.

if not, you can add one **if statement** into that.
Good lucky.
Sorry for made by hand.

Comment: what mean limit_value?

Comment: This is your allow left value in screen.

Comment: I think it is better to use '%' not 'px'

Comment: If screen may be different pixel, it is working well?

Comment: You can see @DmitriyGusev's comment below answer.
And see that url.

Comment: So limit_value should be changed each screen?

Comment: If you use '%', it doesn't need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should to get of that left value when you click any date.
And you set it manually.
I think it is very good method.

Comment: So could you tell me more detail about your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like that.

```
    if(e.schedule){
      popup_layer.style.left ='0%';  
    } else {
      if (e.guide.guideElements[e.guide.startCoord[1]].style.left > 60)
        popup_layer.style.left = '60%';
      else
        popup_layer.style.left = e.guide.guideElements[e.guide.startCoord[1]].style.left;
    }
```

Here, we should change 'px' to '%'.
In here, '**60**' in **if statement** is **limit value** for right-end.

Comment: because you did compare with string and int value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(e.schedule){
  popup_layer.style.left ='0px';  
} else {
  if (parseInt(e.guide.guideElements[e.guide.startCoord[1]].style.left) > 60)
    popup_layer.style.left = '60%';
  else
    popup_layer.style.left = e.guide.guideElements[e.guide.startCoord[1]].style.left;
}
```

Comment: If I need to change top, how should I ?